# get all websockets receive data with javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket

i want to get all receiving data in websocket that i do not have main socket variable name

i want some javascript code to get all data

Please note that I do not have the names of the variables and I want a general state

Answer (score 0):

Open developer tools, go to the network tab, locate the websocket by connection type (or filter). Once you've located it, you can inspect the frames.

In Chrome you will also get "initiator" details pointing to the javascript line where it's being opened

Comment: Recursively traverse every window propoerty cheking if `x instanceof WebSocket`. Good luck